# How to use conference transfer in avaya aaod to ensure that ivr does not exit during transfer

Tags: ivr, avaya

I used the built-in "consultation transfer" ,the "conference" and "Trasfer" in AES. None of them can realize my function. This way I can get their complete recordings. Is there any way you can implement this function in od? Thanks in advance.
[built-in Trasfer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ayEq.png)
[AES Trasfer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN9Mt.png)

These are the two ways I tried, using the built-in Trasfer and the AES conference.
Are these two methods used correctly?
[Consulation Transfer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np0hG.png)
[AES Conference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAD89.png)